# Choosing data storage type in android

Tags: android, database

I'm creating an android app. I have problem with picking the right data storage option.

All the data will be premade, small, not edited and loaded frequently.

The data will be structured, that's why at the beginning I thought about sqlite database(with one table and only about 20 records). But the limit for text size stored in a single field is 255 chars, and I will probably have fields that will be about 500 chars.

What is the best storage option for me?

Comment: If the data is structured, why is the limit of 255 chars a problem? You aren't thinking of storing the whole structure as a single VARCHAR field, are you?

Comment: No :) I just would like to have a field "description" where there will be longer text (about 500 chars). I guess I will need to divide "description" into sections.

Comment: Check out the link in @alex's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you get the 500 char limit from? The [SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) say 1,000,000,000 bytes.

Although, you really should consider structuring your data so that there isn't the need for a giganto field.

Usually, when I have some static application data I package it as XML ot JSON in my resources and parse it into objects at runtime. You can cache it if you're reading it a lot.